# Как работает метод ToString()?

Tags: c#, .net

Я ради интереса хотел узнать как работает метод ToString() (например, преобразование целого числа 10 в строку "10"). Моя цель узнать как это происходит на уровне кода шаг за шагом. В referencesource.microsoft.com я нашел код ниже, но ничего понял или не то нашел. Скажите пожалуйста, где найти информацию по моему вопросу?

```
    public override String ToString() {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        return this;
    }

    public String ToString(IFormatProvider provider) {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Метод чего? У разных типов он может работать по разному.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Например, преобразование целого числа в строк. Из Вашего ответа я понял, что ToString() у кажого типа свой. Верно?

Comment: Верно..........

Comment: Вы смотрите код String.ToString, который ничего не делает... Преобразование чисел в строку в .NET Framework реализовано на С++, если хотите управляемую реализацию, надо смотреть исходники .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/75fede653b46ddb2830f7de2399e7000e6574d4f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs#L1355

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ветка не та, надо `main`. Я кстати удивлен, почему они через `string.Create` это еще не переписали. Быть может пока не успели.

Comment: @aepot это и есть main, просто я дал ссылку на конкретный коммит, чтобы она не протухла. Ссылка ведет на конкретную строку, а номера строк могут поменяться.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ах вон оно что. )

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Странно, а в исходниках всё на C#: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Number.Formatting.cs,c66436177df5dc9b (трассировал отсюда: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252)

Comment: @VladD Это .NET Core, та же ссылка, что и у меня, только в Source Browser. На С++ реализован Number.FormatInt32 в .NET Framework: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,8795e4669ff5e9d0

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Ну, в Fx да, там было много нативного кода, но в Core от него последовательно избавляются (с приростом производительности).

Comment: @VladD в чем прикол смотреть в дотнет через сорц-браузер, не через гитхаб?

Comment: @aepot: Ну например, навигация: имя метода — сразу ссылка на его определение. Есть поиск точек использования. А на гитхабе только поиск по подстроке. И вообще поиск на source.dot.net лучше, я на гитхабе с лёту не смог найти `struct Int32`, а на на source.dot.net за две секунды.